# Use a COM object in .NET 2.0 CF without calling CreateObject

Tags: com, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I need to use a COM object in my .NET 2.0 compact framework project, but I can't use the CreateObject function. Is there any other way to call a COM object that will work in my environment?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to call CoCreateInstance().  You can find a P/Invoke declaration for [it here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/ole32/CoCreateInstance.html).  If you only have a ProgID then you need to call CLSIDFromProgID() first.  Make sure you've exhausted all possibilities of finding a type library for the COM server (Tlbimp.exe), this kind of code isn't easy to get right.